# How to avoid removing the shared COM Interface entry from registry while unregistering the com based application?

Tags: visual-c++, com

While unregistering my .exe (COM based), it is removing the common Interface Id from the registry which is used among several application. How can i avoid deleting common interface from the registry upon unregistering the application

Comment: Not to kick in an opened door, but just don't remove it in your unregistration code.  Having a separate proxy/stub DLL that marshals the interface certainly helps with that.

Comment: Here's a question about a similar scenario with proxy-stubs http://stackoverflow.com/q/1807743/57428 It looks like once you have a proprietary interface and more then one implementation thereof you're just screwed.

Answer (score 2):

Registry typically get IID entries with type library registration, for the interfaces contained within the type library in question. Having certain interface contained in multiple type libraries is the problem in first place. Once you designed your application this way, you started having posted problem as a consequence and side effect.

So the correct solution is to have each interface and IID contained in one type library once, so that IID duplication takes place.

A quick'n'dirty workaround can be that with unregistering specific application, you re-register other installed applciations (their type libraries, in particular) to give them a chance to re-add the deleted entries back onto registry.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Instead of re-registering other applications, is there any way to add/register only the Interface Ids back to registry? Morever, it is not possible for me to re-register other aplications particulars.

Comment: You will still have to chose among `1` do not unregister `2` re-register other `3` redesign properly to avoid duplicating `IID`s in multiple libraries.